# ldap search with special character('+') returns null

Tags: ldap, python-ldap

I want to search a particular ldap-node within groups by unique-member attribute.
Something like.

```
search_filter = 'uniqueMember=mail='testuser.+abc@abc.com',ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com'
```

When I search this filer with

```
conn.search_s(node_dn, ldap.SCOPE_BASE, search_filter, [])
```

It returns {'info': '', 'desc': 'Bad search filter'}.

Whereas a similar search for search_filter without '+'

```
search_filter = 'uniqueMember=mail='testuser.abc@abc.com',ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com'
```

returns desired output.

I've tried escaping all possible ways. like

```
a. uniqueMember=mail='testuser.\+abc@abc.com',ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com
b. uniqueMember=mail='testuser.\\+abc@abc.com',ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com
c. uniqueMember=mail='testuser.\2Babc@abc.com',ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com
d. uniqueMember=mail='testuser.\\2Babc@abc.com',ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com
```

I tried '\2B' as this is how I could see uniqueMember attribute in apache-directory studio.

I'm using python-ldap 2.2.0 with port389.

Is there anything I'm missing while configuring port389. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign `+` indicates that the RDN is multi-valued.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Search Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: Not really clear from the article you mentioned how to address this particular scenario. The need is to find uniqueMember. But it should work when there is a "+" in their email address. Is that even possible ?

Comment: As I wrote, the `+` indicates that the value of `uniqueMember` has a multi-valued RDN, there is nothing special about it. `uniqueMember` has DN syntax, so again, no mystery there. The web page and all the pages it references should contain all the information needed.